# Smalltalk and Assertions

Tags: smalltalk, assertions, gnu-smalltalk

Tryng out some smalltalk + TDD + "good practices" I've run into a kinda ugly block:

How do I do an assertion in GNU Smalltalk?

I'm just looking for a simple `ifFalse: [Die]` kind of thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the code for assert: from [Squeak](http://www.squeak.org/) (which I recommend you use rather than GNU):

```
assert: aBlock 
    "Throw an assertion error if aBlock does not evaluates to true."
    aBlock value
        ifFalse: [AssertionFailure signal: 'Assertion failed']
```

Comment: Why would you not recommend the GNU version?

Comment: Lack of support - squeak has a more involved community, plus Squeak is more fun.

Comment: More support comes from more people using it. And GNU Smalltalk is actually evolving nicely. There are quite some people behind, with Paolo Bonzini as main force.

Comment: Dont listen to the die-hard Squeakers, they just haven't seen a file system in years :) You can have fun with any Smalltalk.

Answer (score 2):

as well as
self assert: [ ... some block ]

works for blocks & non-blocks, since sending #value to Object returns self.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple. In your test methods you write:

```
self assert: 1 + 1 = 2
```

But first you need to create a test class as a subclass of TestCase (in Squeak), for example:

```
TestCase subclass: #MyTest
```

Here you write testing methods, which names must always start with 'test', for instance :

```
testBasicArithmetics

self assert: 1 + 1 = 2
```

Comment: Plainly doing that reports that "Matrix does not understand #assert:".

Comment: Yes, you need to make a test class of course and put assertions in test methods there. See my update.

Comment: Sorry, it was a misunderstanding: I don't mean unit-test assertions, but design-by-contract assertions. (IE, pre/post-condition checking within the method.)

Answer (score 0):

It has been suggested above to add `#assert:` to `Object`, but rather I'd add `#assert` to `BlockClosure` (or whatever `[] class` is in GNU Smalltalk).

```
assert
    this value ifFalse: [AssertionFailure signal: 'Assertion failed']
```

and thus use as in

```
[ value notNil ] assert.
[ value > 0 ] assert.
[ list isEmpty not ] assert.
```

etcetera.

Comment: Why not a method on booleans? `(value > 0) surely.` I guess because the test might produce a non-boolean or an exception, though it doesn't seem like the Smalltalk way to worry much about that.